# Summing the most recent rows, grouped by the id

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT distinct on (prices.item_id) *
FROM prices
ORDER BY prices.item_id, prices.updated_at DESC
```

The above query retrieves the most recent prices, how would I get the total sum of all the current prices?

Is it possible without using a subselect?

Comment: Doesn't that retrieve all of the prices, ordered by descending date?

Comment: Nope, it only retrieves the most recent rows based on descending dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial using a subquery:

```
select sum(p.price)
from (select distinct on (p.item_id) p.*
      from prices p
      order by p.item_id, p.updated_at desc
     ) p
```

If you don't mind repeated rows, I think the following might work:

```
select distinct on (p.item_id) sum(prices.price) over ()
from prices p
order by p.item_id, p.updated_at desc
```

You might be able to add a limit clause to this to get what you want.  By the way, I would write this as:

```
select sum(p.price)
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.item_id order by updated_at desc) as seqnum
      from prices p
      order by p.item_id, p.updated_at desc
     ) p
where seqnum = 1
```

ROW_NUMBER() is standard SQL.  The DISTINCT ON clause is specific to Postgres.

Comment: Such an easy thing, hah! Thanks for that and the bit about row_number